# How to remove prefix from ansible output

Tags: ansible

I have to parse a string in a ansible but when I try to use regex , it creates array.

here is the code

```
- name: "Reindexing {{item}} to local  server "
  ignore_errors: yes
  uri:
    url: "{{proto}}://{{new_server}}:{{es_api_port}}/_reindex?wait_for_completion=false"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Authorization: 'Basic auth=='
    body:
      source :
        index: "{{ item }}" 
      dest:
        index: "{{ item.split('reindex-') | to_nice_json}}" 
    body_format: json
    with_items:
       - reindex-abc-def-ghi--2020-08-31
       - reindex-abc-def-ghi--2020-08-30
```

output is:

```
        "module_args": {
        "attributes": null,
        "body": {
            "dest": {
                "index": "[\n    \"\",\n    \"abc-def-ghi-2020-08-31\"\n]"
            },
            "source": {
                "index": "reindex-abc-def-ghi--2020-08-31"
            }
        },
```

so, In output, dest is showing [\n    "",\n    "abc-def-ghi-2020-08-31"\n]. I am just looking for this "abc-def-ghi-2020-08-31"

Thanks!

Comment: There is no loop in your example an we have no idea what the variable `item` contains, so there's not much help we can provide.

Comment: another playbook is calling this one. Updated the original question

Comment: That doesn't help. This question needs to include a [mcve] -- sufficient code and data to reproduce the problem you're asking about. Without that, there's not much we can do.

Comment: noted. Thanks for letting me know. I have updated my question with minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In output, dest is showing [\n "",\n "abc-def-ghi-2020-08-31"\n].

That's because you're passing the output of `item.split()` to `to_nice_json`, which is for nicely formatting (e.g., with multiple lines and indentation) JSON documents. Why are you using that here?

The result of `item.split('reindex-')` is a two-element list, `["", "abc-def-ghi--2020-08-30"]`. If you just want the second element, you can write:

```
dest:
  index: "{{ item.split('reindex').1 }}"
```